# Homogeneous queue with base class objects ( dequeuing with typeid alternatives )

Tags: c++

I am working on a homogeneous queue of base class pointers to sub class element and while dequeuing I want to act on the actual types but do not want to use the visitor or multi method and avoid virtual tables completely. I am OK to have tight coupling and gain performance and want to avoid any if else in order to achieve it( best to have events be aware of processing functions ahead of time )
In order to achieve that I want to have queue elements to be aware of what function needs to be called for the specific sub class elements.
What is the best way to templatize it to make it generic enough and avoid virtual methods overhead.
It is something like the visitors know about the accept method ahead of time.

Comment: I think virtual methods are by far the best pattern here. Of course you can start fiddling with type tags (like numeric IDs) and tables of function pointers yourself but why would anybody do that? It wouldn't even be faster.

Comment: Please let me know if it is not too clear

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand. What should I let you know?

Comment: You must compare the overhead of the virtual-function mechanism with the overhead your self-made solution would incur. Nothing comes for free, neither virtual functions nor your replacement.

Comment: What if I add the functor to each event how it needs to be handled before I enqueue them and just static_cast them in the function itself avoiding any overhead apart from additional overhead of setting the functor which has to be much lower

Comment: The point which I am trying to make is that my event types in the hierarchy will not grow and hence no need to worry about the extensibility here and I can afford to be tightly coupled with the queue itself

Comment: I just stumbled over this insightful article: http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2013/12/05/the-cost-of-dynamic-virtual-calls-vs-static-crtp-dispatch-in-c. It addresses specifically your question of the cost of virtual calls, and shows that they can indeed be very expensive (for an extremely small function, that is -- obviously big functions will dominate the run time no matter how they are called). **The main killer is inlining.** If you can inline you are good. General guideline for inlining: Make the function implementation visible where it's called. Hard to imagine with a generic queue.

Comment: Note that "normal" function call vs. virtual function call is not the decisive difference. The issue is the function call *per se.* The problem with a virtual function call is that in the general case the compiler will not know which code to inline since the object's type is not generally known at compile time, as opposed to a non-polymorphic object calling a normal member function. The member function can potentially be inlined even across translation unit boundaries when link time / whole program optimization is active.

Comment: Thanks Peter ... Let me get I to this one and see if I can achieve the benchmarks ( I do understand the inlining point here )